# Azure openai load testing mode

Tags: azure, load-testing, openai-api, azure-openai, azure-load-testing

Diving deep into azure development and can't find any logical solution for load testing of AppService that is using OpenAI services.

I suppose there should be some "load testing mode" for Azure Open AI. Maybe separate testing model that will behave like a regular OpenAI model but will not cost a lot of money as a real one does. But I can't find one.

There is always an option to mock calls to OpenAI and simulate response with some delay but I can't believe Microsoft doesn't have smart solution.